# smooth render - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search, render

I have a React Native App with a simple Flatlist. 
I have implemented a searchBar with some search logic that highlights the searched text in the list. (as shown in the video below)

https://youtu.be/lN9vG3-yEpY

Search logic works fine.
Highlight logic works fine.

But as shown in the video when I delete each word in the search bar the rendering of the Flatlist is not smooth.

Code:

```
renderItem({item}) {
    return < FlatListItem item={item} onPress={() => {this.goToDetails(item)} />
  }


<FlatList
        ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ paddingBottom: 50 }}></View>}
        data={notifications}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
        refreshControl={this.refreshControl()}
         />
```

```
class FlatListItem extends Component {

render() {

     escape = function( value ) {
      return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$%#\s]/g, "\\$&");
 }


    getHighlightedText = text => {       // Highlight logic 
      const {value} = this.props;
      
      if(value == "" || value == null || value == 0){
        return <Text> {text} </Text>
      }
      else{
      const words = value.split(/\s+/g).filter(word => word.length);
      const pattern = words.join('|');
      const tex = escape(pattern);
      const re = new RegExp(tex, 'gi')
      const children = [];
      let before, highlighted, match, pos = 0;
      const matches = text.match(re);

      if(matches != null){
      for( match of matches ){
        match = re.exec(text)
        if(pos < match.index) {
          before = text.substring(pos, match.index);
          if(before.length){
            children.push(before)
          }
        }
        highlighted = <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'coral'}} key={match.index + match[0].length}>{match[0]}</Text> 
        children.push(highlighted);    
        pos = match.index + match[0].length;
      }
    }

      if(pos < text.length){
        const last = text.substring(pos);
        children.push(last);
      }
      return <Text>{children}</Text>
    }
  }

 return (
     <Text numberOfLines={3} onTextLayout={(event, lines) => this.measureView(event, lines)}>{value !== "" ? getHighlightedText(alert) : alert}</Text>   
               
)

}
```

How can I make this right? 
When I delete a letter the Flatlist should render smoothly.
Currently its rendering really fast which looks very confusing to the user. Is this because of my Highlight function???

Comment: Begin by taking any bound or arrow functions out of the JSX. When you bind a function, it returns a new function, so when React does it's diff it will see a new prop and re-render. This is why in classes you bind in the constructor. You can also use es6 shorthand with a class.
`renderItem = ({ item }) => { // logic }`.

In the FlatList, move the ListFooterComponent, keyExtractor, renderItem, and the return of refreshControl out of the JSX and into their own functions, so they don't force a re-render

Comment: Also, is all of that logic in your child's render? Move it all out. Right now for each item, all of that code is running for each item.

Comment: @Yoshi, thanks for the input. you mean my "getHighlightedText" function should be removed from render(){...}? I should place it outside render correct?

Comment: @Yoshi, "take any bound or arrow functions out of the JSX" u mean functions like this "onTextLayout={(event, lines) => this.measureView(event, lines)" should be out of the JSX???

Comment: Ideally yes, especially when you're having performance issues. React lifecycles will trigger on state or prop changes. When you define an function inline in the JSX props, it creates a new function every time, thus a new prop, and probably a new render. If you define it as a class method or wrapped callback with useCallback in a functional component, the reference to the function is always the same, so it won't cause unnecessary re-renders. @pringles